# Replacement for Hardware Growler?

Tags: command-line, hardware, automator, growl

Having just made the leap to Sierra (10.12.2), I've discovered that one of my favorite add-ons is behaving funkily, and wonder if any of you have discovered an alternative.

I don't actually care that much about Growl itself, but Hardware Growler is a wonderful add-on to Growl that gives you all sorts of info about what's going on behind the scenes with the hardware you connect/disconnect from it. Everything from USB, Bluetooth & Firewire to Network, Power and Volume mounting/unmounting.

Since it's primarily just reporting things that system doing & noticing, I would imagine there might be something like an Automator workflow, integrated with some command line tools that could replace it?

---

I'm using version 2.1.3 of Growl, which is the latest, and what I was using in El Capitan. HardwareGrowler is at version 2.2, and again, that's what I have been using for quite some time.

Comment: What version did you upgrade from?

Comment: I'm using version 2.1.3 of Growl, which is the latest, and what I was using in El Cap. HardwareGrowler is at version 2.2, and again, that's what I have been using for quite some time. The issue is that the entire Growl ecosystem hasn't been modified since 2013, and I don't believe it's being developed any longer.

Answer (score 1):

I just upgraded to High Sierra and version 2.1.3 which is the latest, and you get get it from the App store, download it or build it yourself from Github.  Works very well, I had to add it to the startup items.  Other than that, still works.

Comment: This has been my experience as well.  I'm on macOS 10.13.6, where Growl, HardwareGrowler, and various other Growl addons are all behaving just fine.  If someone finds them not working right, I would suggest reinstalling Growl, etc. (and throw out their original prefs files), since it would seem that something else that came along later interfered with one or another of them, or one of the prefs files got corrupted. I can't speak for macOS 10.14+; my old Mac won't upgrade to 10.14. I don't consider 10.15 an upgrade, since it breaks thousands of 32-bit apps, i.e. lights users' money on fire.)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a replacement for Hardware Growler, sadly (I use it a great deal, myself). What I will say, if you don't have a need for Growl itself anymore, except for Hardware Growler, the good news is that [Hardware Growler](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hardwaregrowler/id475260933?mt=12) is a standalone application that will send Notifications directly to Notification Center.

I might try completely uninstalling both Growl and Hardware Growler, and reinstalling just HG.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Do let me know if you end up trying that; hopefully it works!

Comment: Err, I have. Peculiarities of the English language, I think - “If I were you I might try etc etc.” I haven’t used Growl or had it installed in several years, and Hardware Growler has been working just fine. As far as your original question goes, Hammerspoon is probably the closest to a real hardware notifier that I’ve found, but it’s really designed to notify/trigger on *specific* hardware insertion, not broad system events.

Comment: Turns out I must've already done that some time ago! Typical...  Thanks again anyway!!